# Flutter upgrade can't run on VSC

Tags: flutter

While trying to run, I am getting this particular error :

```
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
  Command: git fetch --tags
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to run `flutter doctor` to find the problem or you just can update it manually by run `flutter upgrade` on your command prompt